# LED Pixel density , LED Pixel height and width , Resolution

Tags: android

Can some one explain me the relation between 
    **LED Pixel density,**
    **LED Pixel height and width** , **and
    Resolution**
while creating an emulator
in detailed way.. 
and again while launching 
Default:   SkinSize, Density;
Scale density to realsize ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pixel density :** Pixels per inch (PPI) or pixel density is a measurement of the resolution of devices in various contexts: typically computer displays, image scanners, and digital camera image sensors.

**Resolution**: or the total number of pixels in a display, is a very important factor that affects the performance of the sign. More resolution means more LED diodes and more circuits, which usually means better picture quality.

Pixel have fixed size height and width, it's just a dot, the no of dots in an inch creates resolution.

Comment: @Sandy09 on some devices pixels are not square or dots as you might imply from the post.  In this case, the emulator allows you to specify the exact dimensions of the actual pixels.